Reduced airport capacity and EC261 compensation
I have now been in the following situation twice: My flight connection involves Airport S, which tends to run at full capacity. Due to unfavourable weather the capacity at S has to be reduced. My flight is one of the few to be cancelled, while most others go ahead as planned or slightly delayed. The airline denies EC261 compensation, claiming that the root cause is weather and thus beyond their control.
I am somewhat suspicious of their reasoning, as the immediate reason for my flight being cancelled would seem to be an operational decision to sacrifice this specific flight rather than some other. My question is whether there is any case law or other authorative statement on how this is meant to work.

As far as I understand it, anything that is a consequence of ATC decisions is deemed extraordinary circumstances and out of scope for EC261 compensation. What airport is that, though?

@jcaron Schiphol (but that shouldn't matter, right?)

just trying to figure out how come they have such issues so often that you are affected repeatedly.
